# Object.create() and native private fields

Tags: javascript

When I create instance of a class via `Object.create(Example.prototype)` to bypass its constructor, it is no longer possible to work with native private fields:

```js
class Example {
  #myPrivateProp;

  setup() {
    this.#myPrivateProp = 1;
  }
}

const e1 = new Example();
const e2 = Object.create(Example.prototype);
console.log(e1.setup()); // works
console.log(e2.setup()); // fails with Uncaught TypeError: Cannot write private member #myPrivateProp to an object whose class did not declare it
```

Is there a way to make this work, while maintining the invariant of not calling the constructor?

For context you can see this issue: https://github.com/mikro-orm/mikro-orm/issues/1226

Comment: When using native private fields, **no**.

Comment: This is exactly why private fields are a bad idea: they break reflection. Whoever wants to use them needs to be aware of this.

Comment: For your context: the person defining the private field is responsible for also providing a `serialise`/`deserialise` (or `toJSON`/`fromJSON`) method pair. You can try deriving one with your decorator, but it will involve calling the constructor. (Which actually should not be a problem if the constructor is written properly and only initialises the instance, not executing side effects).

Answer (score -1):

What you are defining here is not a [private field](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Private_class_fields#syntax) but a [private instance field](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Private_class_fields#private_instance_fields). A private instance field is there not to be exposed and manipulated by others except that very instance. You shouldn't be able to clone that very instance along with it's state, manipulate it and replace the original one.

You have two options;

1. A static private field that belongs to the `Example` class which can be accessed and manipulated mutually by any instance of that class or even by objects created like `Object.create(Example.prototype)`.

such as;

```
class Example {
  static #SECRET = 0;
  constructor(){
  }

  addOne() {
    return ++Example.#SECRET;
  }
}


i1 = new Example();
i2 = new Example();
console.log(i1.addOne()); // <- 1
console.log(i2.addOne()); // <- 2
i3 = Object.create(Example.prototype);
console.log(i3.addOne()); // <- 3
Example.#SECRET = 4;      // <- Uncaught SyntaxError: Private field '#SECRET' must be
                          //    declared in an enclosing class
```

2. The private instance field belongs to the instance and can only be accessed and manipulated by that very instance. How this is achieved is exactly seen in your example code. Every single instance will have it's own `#myPrivateProp` which, if you ask me, is a beautiful thing. [For example one can instantiate many individual Queues](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/255817/105433) and their operationaly critical properties wouldn't be exposed.

Comment: "*not a private field but a private instance field.*" - uh, a private instance field is just a specific kind of private field.

Comment: "*A private instance field belongs to the instance and can only be accessed and manipulated by that very instance*" - that's not true. A private field can be accessed by any code inside the `class`, from static methods as well as methods that were called on other instances. Did you mean "can only be accessed **through** the instance"? But that's not any different from a normal instance-specific property.

Comment: I don't really see how this answers the question about calling the `setup()` method on an object instantiated with `Object.create`